# Can anyone understand this step from a Kutta-Joukowski theorem derivation?

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, physics

I'm currently studying Aerodynamics. A theorem very usefull that I'm learning is the Kutta-Joukowski theorem for forces and moment applied on an airfoil. I have a doubt about a mathematical step from the derivation of this theorem, which I found on a theoretical book. This step is shown on the image bellow:

---

[image]

(This is from a portuguese book. It's "Aerodinâmica Incompressível: Fundamentos" by Vasco Brederode http://istpress.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/node/392)

---

In the first part of this image there's an approximation by Taylor series expansion for the function $z=F(\zeta)$, so that we get:

$$z=F(\zeta)=\zeta+\frac{b^2}{\zeta}\hspace{15pt} (1)$$

[**Note:** $b$ is a real constant]

This part I totally understand. My doubt is about the final part. The inversion of the function $F(\zeta)$ it's a little obscure. I **think** that the author of this book did the following:

> From (1) we get:
>
> $$\zeta^2-z\zeta+b^2=0\Leftrightarrow \zeta=\frac{1}{2}\left(z\pm\sqrt{z^2-4b^2}\right)$$
>   where $\sqrt{z^2-4b^2}$ is the principal square root of $z^2-4b^2$.
>
> Now, we can write $\sqrt{z^2-4b^2}=z\sqrt{1-4\left(\frac{b}{z}\right)^2}$, and expand the square root in Taylors series of $\frac{b}{z}$ around $\frac{b}{z}=0$ to give:
>
> $$\zeta=\frac{1}{2}z\left[1\pm\sqrt{1-4\left(\frac{b}{z}\right)^2}\right]=\frac{1}{2}z\left\{ 1\pm\left[1-2\left(\frac{b}{z}\right)^2+...\right]\right\} $$
>
> Now I think he choose the "+" branch (I wouldn't know why) and got the final result:
>
> $$\zeta=z\left[1-\left(\frac{b}{z}\right)^2+...\right]$$

Anyway, I think that this isn't right because of the choice of the "+" branch. I reall don't find have any reason for that.

How do you interpret this step?

Comment: Well, it's a Laurent expansion, and the condition $|s/\zeta|<1$ shows we're in a neighborhood of infinity, here. We're given $$z=\zeta\left(1+\frac{b^2}{\zeta^2}+O(|\zeta|^{-3})\right),$$ this clearly implies$$\zeta=z\left(1-\frac{b^2}{\zeta^2}+O(|\zeta|^{-3})\right),$$ and substituting this into itself gives$$\zeta=z\left(1-\frac{b^2}{z^2}+O(|\zeta|^{-3})\right)=z\left(1-\frac{b^2}{z^2}+O(|z|^{-3})\right).$$

Comment: How did you get from the first relation to the second one? You did another laurent expansion, didn't you?

Comment: I will accept your answer if you explain those details. Thank you

Comment: Ok. Please, tell me if it's detailed enough, I'm ready to elaborate if necessary.

Comment: I think that's the right answer. I will accept it, and try it by myself! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's a Laurent expansion, and the condition $|s/\zeta|<1$ shows we're in a neighborhood of infinity, here. We're given $$z=\zeta\left(1+\frac{b^2}{\zeta^2}+O(|\zeta|^{-3})\right),$$ this implies$$\zeta=z\left(1-\frac{b^2}{\zeta^2}+O(|\zeta|^{-3})\right),$$ since $$\frac1{1+\frac{b^2}{\zeta^2}+O(|\zeta|^{-3})}=1-\frac{b^2}{\zeta^2}+O(|\zeta|^{-3}),$$ and substituting this into itself gives$$\zeta=z\left(1-\frac{b^2}{z^2}+O(|\zeta|^{-3})\right)=z\left(1-\frac{b^2}{z^2}+O(|z|^{-3})\right),$$ since $|z/\zeta|$ will be bounded from above and below for $|\zeta|$ big enough ($\lim_{\zeta\to\infty}z/\zeta=1$).

Comment: I have a doubt. I can't achieve $O(|\zeta|^{-3})=O(|z|^{-3})$. How did you get it?

Comment: @Élio Pereira I've edited the answer. Is that better?

Comment: So we can only say that $O(|\zeta|^{-3})=O(|z|^{-3})$ when $|\zeta|\to\infty$?

Comment: @Élio Pereira Please, remember: the author assumes $|\zeta|$ to be big ($|b/\zeta|<1$) from the very beginning.

Comment: You're right. I forgot that.